# How do I make the script work with percentage?

Tags: javascript

I have this pop up window being centered by javascript using px. I need the box to be responsive so how can I adjust the script to calculate for percentages and not px. Is it possible? This current code allows me to produce an automatic pop up but it also has script that centers the pop using px. This is not responsive.

```
function toggle(div_id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(div_id);
    if ( el.style.display == 'none' ) { el.style.display = 'block';}
    else {el.style.display = 'none';}
}

    function blanket_size(popUpDivVar) {
        if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
            viewportheight = window.innerHeight;
        } else {
            viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        }
        if ((viewportheight > document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight) && (viewportheight > document.body.parentNode.clientHeight)) {
            blanket_height = viewportheight;
        } else {
            if (document.body.parentNode.clientHeight > document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight) {
                blanket_height = document.body.parentNode.clientHeight;
            } else {
                blanket_height = document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight;
            }
        }
        var blanket = document.getElementById('blanket');
        blanket.style.height = blanket_height + 'px';
        var popUpDiv = document.getElementById(popUpDivVar);
        popUpDiv_height=blanket_height/2-187.5;//200 is half popup's height
        popUpDiv.style.top = popUpDiv_height + 'px';
    }
    function window_pos(popUpDivVar) {
        if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
            viewportwidth = window.innerHeight;
        } else {
            viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        }
        if ((viewportwidth > document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth) && (viewportwidth > document.body.parentNode.clientWidth)) {
            window_width = viewportwidth;
        } else {
            if (document.body.parentNode.clientWidth > document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth) {
                window_width = document.body.parentNode.clientWidth;
            } else {
                window_width = document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth;
            }
        }
        var popUpDiv = document.getElementById(popUpDivVar);
        window_width=window_width/2-250;//200 is half popup's width
        popUpDiv.style.left = window_width + 'px';
    }
    function popup(windowname) {
        blanket_size(windowname);
        window_pos(windowname);
        toggle('blanket');
        toggle(windowname);     
    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? A modal dialog centered in the screen when you click a button or something?

Comment: this is an automatic pop up this current code does that but is also requires that you use px to center the box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like an awful lot of javascript to display a popup dialog. You can accomplish this functionality with CSS/HTML alone, although many solutions will use HTML/CSS for the layout, and some javascript to show/hide the dialog.

I dont like to use javascript at all for the actual layout of the webpage, such as positioning elements. CSS was designed specifically for positioning and styling web elements, and it is generally more efficient than JS.

You may want to check out some of the many guides available online for HTML/CSS Modal Dialogs. These are done with minimal javascript.

Check out this one for starters

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/

Good luck

Comment: Is there a way to do this automatically without the user having to click something?

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need JavaScript to center something - for that, we have CSS! To center something horizontally, simply use the following CSS on the element

```
margin: auto;
```

To center something vertically, you can use something like

```
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
position:relative;
```